# How to set up bash autocompletion to deal with file names like "./foo=bar/x=y.txt"?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

When I start typing a file name that contains an equal sign, autocompletion with [tab] shows a strange behaviour:

```
ls ./foo[tab]    # autocompletion to "./foo\=bar"         <- ok
ls ./foo=[tab]   # autocompletion to "./foo=foo\=bar/"    <- not ok
```

Is there something I can put into .bashrc to control this behavior or change some autocomplete scripts in /etc?

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. Or, at least, it will be really complex. The problem here is that `foo=` is interpreted by bash as an attempt to set the variable `foo` to something. So, when you hit <kbd>tab</kbd> it tries to complete with the names of the files in the current directory. It isn't actually completing `foo=`, it is starting a whole new glob from nothing. Note that it takes two tabs to complete `foo=`.

To illustrate, you can see the same behavior even if there are no files starting with `foo=`:

```
$ ls
bar  baz
```

Typing `foo=` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> results in:

```
$ foo= ## first tab does nothing
$ foo= 
bar          baz  ## both file names are printed.
```

I doubt there's going to be any way around this since this is a basic function of the shell and the primary way to define variables.

I can think of two workarounds. Either escape the `=`:

```
$ ls foo\=  ## hit tab
$ ls foo\=bar
```

Or use quotes:

```
$ ls 'foo=     ## hit tab
$ ls 'foo=bar' ## yes, the final quote is added by the shell.
```

Hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> now will expand the file name correctly.